# random forest with sub_balanced returns nan everything

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, random-forest, grid-search

Pretty straightforward... I'm running a GridSearchCV, with the following code:

```
params = {'n_estimators':[10,20,50,100,200], 
          'max_features':['sqrt','log2',None],
          'class_weight':['balanced', 'sub_balanced'],
          'criterion':['gini','entropy'],
          'oob_score':[True,False]}

estimator = RandomForestClassifier()

grid_rf_balanced = GridSearchCV(estimator, param_grid=params,scoring=scoring,cv=cv,verbose=1,n_jobs=-1, refit='avg_micro_precision', return_train_score=True)

grid_rf_balanced.fit(X, y, groups= clusters)

results_balanced = pd.DataFrame(grid_rf_balanced.cv_results_)
```

Here you can see what I mean with nan values:

[click here for image please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezKOP.png)

I basically get results for the "balanced" weights but absolutely no results for "sub_balanced" (they're ALL nan)

Any ideas? A detail: I'm working with multiclass classification.

Comment: Could you include the data you are using?

Comment: @yuRa Just added it!

Comment: "sub_balanced" is not a valid value for `class_weights`...did you mean to use "balanced_subsample"?

Comment: *facepalm* thanks Ben.... reminder to self: do not write code at 3 am.